# firebase storage is deleting my images when i try to download them

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage, imagedownload

Whenever i run the following code firebase storage is deleting my image. My Log.d prints out the correct file location. I don't know why my images are being deleted instead of downloaded. `

```
    override fun getImage(url:String) = callbackFlow {
        val size: Long = 1024 * 1024 * 20 //20MB
        val storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images/${url}")
        Log.d("TEST", storageRef.toString())
        storageRef.getBytes(size).addOnSuccessListener {
            trySend(Response.Success(it))
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            trySend(Response.Failure(it))
        }
        awaitClose{
            storageRef.delete()
        }
    }
```

[image]

i tried different file extensions and just a few changes to code. I tried maximizing the byteArray.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling:

```
storageRef.delete()
```

And `StorageReference.delete()` is [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/kotlin/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#delete()) to:

> Deletes the object at this `StorageReference`.

So if you don't want to delete the image, don't call `delete()` on a reference to the image.